# How to query MongoDB for every document which date that is EQUAL to and WITHIN a start and end-date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to use a "start_date" and "end_date" as query params for so to recieve every document in MongoDB that are same or within this period of time. (PS: I know that $gt and $lt is not achieving what i want)

```
                router.get('/history', async (req, res) => {
                const start = req.query.date_start;
                const end = req.query.date_end;
                if (start === undefined || end === undefined)
                    return res.status(400).send('No query params detected!');
                const query = await History.find({ date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } });
                res.send(query);
            });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your dates are of type string. You have to convert it to a dates object.

You also have to store dates in the database and not string. Because mongo will compare them as and sort them by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$gte` and `$lte`?

```
History.find({ date: { $gte: start, $lte: end } });
```

Comment: Yes, that does not seem to work as it returns other years than requested in Postman.